# How to install django-cms 3 on django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-1.6

I need to run `django-cms 3` on `Django 1.6`, but I couldn't! Does anybody know a step by step tutorial for running `django-cms 3` on `django 1.6`?

Comment: Look at installation documentation of it that refers to version 3.0.0.beta3 : http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/getting_started/installation.html . It's step by step.

Comment: that teached in django 1.5,but I need to django 1.6!

Comment: It's also OK for Django 1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow installation for [development](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/getting_started/installation.html), It's also ok for Django 1.6.1

Here is quick steps:

Install django:

```
pip install django==1.6.1
```

Install django-cms (It will install all requirements of it):

```
pip install https://github.com/divio/django-cms/archive/3.0.0.beta3.zip
```

Install django-cms recommended:

```
pip install djangocms-text-ckeditor
pip install pillow # http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow (windows) 
pip install django-filer
```

Create a sample django project:

```
cd ~/workspace
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Edit `settings.py` as [described](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/getting_started/tutorial.html).

Also be sure to have `'django.contrib.sites'` in `INSTALLED_APP` and set `SITE_ID` parameter in your settings:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Then run following cmds from `myproject` directory to create, sync, update and check your db:

```
python manage.py syncdb --all
python manage.py migrate --fake

python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py cms check
```

Finally run your server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Go to home page, and now you must see `Installation successful!` in django-cms home page, try to login and start adding pages.

Comment: I receive this error:
 'No module named sitesdjango.contrib.messages'

Comment: The `sitesdjango` means you missed `,` between two application string name in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In Python, string can concat together with space as: `'He'` `'llo'` that is `'Hello'`